# Loading Wireless Firmware

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, firmware

I have a laptop with 802.11ad chipset from Wilocity which works perfectly on windows. Whereas, on Ubuntu 16.04.1 it gives me a message that the firmware is missing and not available for download but the driver is already available in the OS. I already have the firmware file (wil6210.fw) so I tried to copy it to /lib/firmware and disable and enable the wireless adapters (In-order to load the firmware) but nothing changed and I am still getting the missing firmware message. Are there more steps that I need to do?

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep wil`

```
[   12.179378] EXT4-fs (sda5): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   12.946471] EXT4-fs (sda7): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   21.112528] wil6210 0000:02:00.0: wil6210 device found [1ae9:0310] (rev 2)
[   21.130367] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): CSR at [mem 0xc1200000-0xc13fffff 64bit] -> 0xffffc90002c00000
[   21.145861] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Board hardware is Sparrow B0
[   21.202753] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Boot Loader struct v2: MAC = 04:ce:14:07:59:21 RF = 0x0000 (status 0x0000) bband = 0x00000000
[   21.202758] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Boot Loader build 255.255.0.6836
[   21.710282] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   23.552807] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: Boot Loader struct v2: MAC = 04:ce:14:07:59:21 RF = 0x0000 (status 0x0000) bband = 0x00000000
[   23.552811] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: Boot Loader build 255.255.0.6836
[   23.552813] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: Use firmware <wil6210.fw> + board <wil6210.brd>
[   23.553080] wil6210 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for wil6210.fw failed with error -2
[   23.553083] wil6210 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: ERR[ FW ]Failed to load firmware wil6210.fw
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep wil` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 here is the output you requested

Comment: The driver evidently wants *both* wil6210.fw *and* wil6210.brd. Do you have both? `ls -al /lib/firmware | grep wil` Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 I added the two files to /lib/firmware and I had to restart the OS inorder to load both of them instead of disabling and enabling the wireless adapters like what I was doing before. Now it seems I can use the driver of the chipset.

Comment: So you are all set and the wireless is working?

Comment: @chili555 I am not sure I still need to test with 60 GHz router. I will update you once I do that

Comment: @chili555 I tried it today with the Router and it works perfectly. However, I am not able to let the interface works in monitor mode despite on [wil6210 website] (https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/wil6210) they mention that. I am able to set the interface in monitor mode but I am not able to see anything on the Wireshark.

Comment: Wireshark is outside my specialty and interest. I suggest you start a new question and reference wireshark in the title.